# Função onfocus no input Select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

Tenho um formulário onde cada campo tem uma ação de salvar, é um "formulário".

Para isso, cada vez que seleciono um campo, um botão de salvar e cancelar aparece para ele.

Entretanto, com um campo `select2`, estes botões não aparecem, o `onfocus` não é ativado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<!-- função exibe / oculta botões -->
<script>
    function acao(input){
        // Quebra condicionais recebidas do campo em que se está trabalhando
        var split = input.split(';');

        if (split[0] == 1) {
            // Exibe botões
            document.getElementById('div'+split[1]).style.display = 'block';

        } else {
            // Oculta botões
            document.getElementById('div'+split[1]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- select comum  -->
<select id="teste" onfocus="acao('1;teste')">
    <option value="id1">nome1</option>
    <option value="id2">nome2</option>
    <option value="id3">nome3</option>
</select>

<!-- Botões de ações para o select -->
<div id="divteste" style="display:none">
    <button type="button">Salvar</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="acao('0;teste')">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- select2 comum, funciona  -->
<select class="teste2" onfocus="acao('1;teste2')">
    <option value="id1">nome1</option>
    <option value="id2">nome2</option>
    <option value="id3">nome3</option>
</select>

<!-- Botões de ações para o select -->
<div id="divteste2" style="display:none">
    <button type="button">Salvar</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="acao('0;teste2')">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<!-- libs -->    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chamada select2, não funciona -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.teste2').select2();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para seu caso, use o evento: `select2:opening`, adicionado ao seu código mais abaixo.**

> **select2:opening** é disparado antes que o menu suspenso seja aberto.

O `Select2` acionará alguns eventos diferentes quando ações diferentes forem executadas usando o componente, permitindo adicionar ganchos personalizados e executar ações. Você também pode disparar manualmente esses eventos em um controle `Select2` usando `.trigger`.

> **Trecho adicionado:**

```
$('.teste2').select2().on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    acao('1;teste2')
});
```

---

***Código:***

```js
function acao(input){
        // Quebra condicionais recebidas do campo em que se está trabalhando
        var split = input.split(';');

        if (split[0] == 1) {
            // Exibe botões
            document.getElementById('div'+ split[1]).style.display = 'block';

        } else {
            // Oculta botões
            document.getElementById('div'+ split[1]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    //Código adicionado
    $('.teste2').select2().on('select2:opening', function (e) {
        acao('1;teste2')
    });
```

```html
<!-- função exibe / oculta botões -->
<!-- select comum  -->
<select id="teste" onfocus="acao('1;teste')">
    <option value="id1">nome1</option>
    <option value="id2">nome2</option>
    <option value="id3">nome3</option>
</select>

<!-- Botões de ações para o select -->
<div id="divteste" style="display:none">
    <button type="button">Salvar</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="acao('0;teste')">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- select2 comum, funciona  -->
<select class="teste2">
    <option value="id1">nome1</option>
    <option value="id2">nome2</option>
    <option value="id3">nome3</option>
</select>

<!-- Botões de ações para o select -->
<div id="divteste2" style="display:none">
    <button type="button">Salvar</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="acao('0;teste2')">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<!-- libs -->    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

> Nas páginas abaixo, há outros exemplos de eventos:

**Fonte:**
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#sidebar-toggle
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Answer (score 0):

olá, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não deixe de votar na pergunta além de aceitá-la como a resposta principal. kkkkkkk